# Ошибка при подключении файлов через include

Tags: php

В проекте для подключения файлов использую include **DIR**.'\func.php'. На опенсервере все работает, а на хостинге ошибка подключения файлов. Хотя все файлы по указанным адресам есть. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема скорее всего связанна с разделителями пути. У вас openserver видимо работает под ОС Windows, которая "понимает" оба варианта разделителя пути к файлу: «\» и «/».
А на хостинге скорее всего Linux, который "воспринимает" только такой разделитель - «/».
Поэтому для решения проблемы можно заменить в путях разделитель на «/».
Так же в php есть предопределенная константа  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, которая возвращает нужный для вашей ОС разделитель.
Можете писать: `include __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'func.php'` и все будет работать корректно.

Comment: Так же, чтоб писать короче, можно создать свою константу на основе DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, например:
const DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR или define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) - если у вас совсем старая версия php.
И затем: include _ _DIR_ _ . DS . 'func.php'.

Comment: Спасибо. все работает